# Pygtk object uninitialized

Tags: python, pygtk

Hi during the creation of multiple objects in pygtk application, calling some of these object return that they are uninitialised when passing there contents to signals (noting the value are showen correctly in the application)

```
sections = config.sections()
for section in sections:
    box= gtk.Table (3,len(config.options(section)),False)
    box.set_col_spacings(2)
    box.set_row_spacings(2)
    box.show()
    label = gtk.Label(section)
    label.show()
    notebook.append_page (box,label)
    for i,option in enumerate(config.options(section)):
        optionlabel = gtk.Label(option)
        optionvalue = gtk.Entry ()
        optionvalue.set_text(config.get(section,option))
    --> optionvalue.connect("activate", enter_callback,optionvalue, label, optionlabel)
        box.attach(optionlabel,0,1,i,i+1,xoptions=gtk.SHRINK|gtk.FILL,yoptions=gtk.SHRINK)
        box.attach(optionvalue,1,2,i,i+1,yoptions=gtk.SHRINK)
    box.show_all()
```

at first I thought that the variables are not in scope but they were ( I've tested several objects and found them working the last 3 lines

```
Linuxcnc ini.py:70: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_entry_get_text: assertion "GTK_IS_ENTRY (entry) failed
  print (widget.get_text())
None
<gtk.Label object at 0x9f44a54 (uninitialized at 0x0)>
<gtk.Label object at 0x9f44c0c (uninitialized at 0x0)>
0
<gtk.Label object at 0x9f4c8ec (GtkLabel at 0xa1a3350)>
<gtk.Label object at 0x9f4dc0c (GtkLabel at 0xa1a3450)>
```

Comment: Without line numbers in your code, it is difficult to relate the error messagse to the actual program (Eg. line 70 is where?). Try to provide a working (minimal example.

Comment: I've marked the 70 line with an arrow to see the problematic instruction, the enter_callback function is stripped just to print the arguments values

def enter_callback( self, widget,section, optionlabel):
 #config.set(section,optionlabel,optionvalue)
 save_button_enable (True)
 print "Entry %s from section %s has contents: %s\n" % (optionlabel , section,widget.get_text())
the value in the entry field is correct but when calling an activate after changing it returns (None)

Answer (score 0):

For this one I think you may need to look in the Gtk system library itself.

(The source code that is used to produce ".so", ".dll" or ".dylib" file, that has the routines that your Python program is accessing).

You can look a the contents of such binary files with commands like "strings", "nm", and "objdump".

But based the nature of the error, it looks like the fix will be done in the source code of the library itself, not the Python program.

Sorry I cannot give more detail than that.